# Inject data from laravel controller into react code

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Deep down in my components tree I have a select tag, which need to be populated by data from the backend. This should happen initially when the page loads.

Is there a way to pass data using `with` in my controller and then into some auxillary js file?

```
return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');
```

An option is doing an API call after component mount but I rather avoid that. What is the best practice here?

Comment: You can always set a variable in the blade file. I assume you're using something like an `index.blade.php`, then in a script or on an element do: `let myData = '{{ $name }}'` or `<input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $name }}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @btl! Works perfect, just adding example here.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome')->with('name', 'Victoria'); });
```

In welcome.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div id="main"></div>
        <script>
            let myData = '{{ $name }}'
        </script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>                
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally in some arbitary jsx file (to be compiled into app.js)

```
<h1>{myData}</h1>
```